# Joomla Version in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, joomla

I have a crashed/hacked Joomla installation (Files and Folders only)
Database has NOT been compromised so I have the DB which is in Good Condition.

I need to find out what was the installed version of Joomla that was live, so I can download that exact version package and reinstall it on a new location.

Is there a table or an entry in the DB that tells me this?

I have a JoomlaPack backup and I also need to know which version of Joomla Pack was installed right before the devastation, so I can restore properly.

thank you

Comment: If all else fails, here is the direct link to the SQL installation files: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Fdevelopment%2Freleases%2F1.5%2Finstallation%2Fsql%2Fmysql%2F you may be able to at least tell the approximate version by comparing the table structures, however that is probably not going to give you a definite result.

Comment: Accodring to this (http://www.torkiljohnsen.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/joomla_15_database_schema.png) I would try to look for it in users & access control. Unfortunetly there is only one entry with "version" and it's stands for the version of one content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research:

The Joomla version is not saved on the DataBase. The Joomla version is saved in a file here:

/libraries/Joomla/version.php

Answer (score 6):

Newer versions of Joomla store the *version of the database schema* in the table jos_schemas (You have to replace jos_ with your database prefix). Look in the row wehere the extension ID is 700. For example it could read:

```
extension_id|version_id
700         |1.7.3-2011-11-10
```

This would indicate that the last Joomla version this database was used with was 1.7.3. (The date behind it is the day the change to the database schema was committed).

This system has been in place at least since Joomla 1.7. For older versions you'll have to resort to different solution. The database schema between version 1.0, 1.5 and 1.6 is very different so it should not be very hard to figure out to which version it belongs by comparing to other installations.

Joomla 1.0 and 1.5 did not change the database schema in minor versions so you can always install the newest minor version of those. Joomla 1.7 and newer will update the database schema themselves if they discover it's outdated, however I wouldn't rely on this when restoring a site.

Lastly your reference to Joomla Pack makes me think you're still using Joomla 1.0 - update! It's an incredibly outdated version.

Comment: Since Joomla 3.2.2 you should check the manifest_cache field of this table.

Answer (score 0):

In joomla 2.x you can also find the version in

> administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml

Comment: This is still true in 3.x and though 4.4.